# Drawing a line using Python script

Tags: python

I would like to draw a simple line using Python script code.
I would like to draw the line from (0,0,0) to (0,0,1)

My philosophy (from what I've seen on the net) is:

Draw a mesh plane (center at (0,0,0))
Select and delete 3 of the 4 vertices (Edit Mode)
Snap (move) the remaining vertex to the center of the plane (original placement point)
 - snap cursor to center
 - select and snap remaining vertex to cursor (now at the center)
Extrude the current vertex to (0,0,1)

I come from a CAD world, so this seems complicated for a simple object like a line, but I'm willing to adapt.

My general task is to draw "stick figures" using lines (between named points).
Being able to "name" the points would be a plus, so I can draw new lines
starting from those named points when needed.

Answer (score 4):

some good reference: [adding geometry](http://blenderscripting.blogspot.com.co/2013/05/adding-geometry-to-existing-geometry.html)

note that you must be in editmode (**EDIT:** to go to edit mode, create a mesh, select it with right-click, and then hit "tab"), and remove doubles after run the script:

```
import bpy, bmesh

obj = bpy.context.object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

v1 = bm.verts.new((2.0, 2.0, 2.0))
v2 = bm.verts.new((-2.0, 2.0, 2.0))
v3 = bm.verts.new((-2.0, -2.0, 2.0))


bm.edges.new((v1, v2))
bm.edges.new((v2, v3))

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(obj.data)
```

if you have the point list, may be you can apply some loops

Comment: Could you please respond on this http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58557/room-for-tak-and-yhoyo ?

Answer (score -1):

See [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.render.html?highlight=draw%20line#bge.render.drawLine)

> `bge.render.drawLine(fromVec, toVec, color)`  Draw a line in the 3D
>   scene.
>
> Parameters:
>
> `fromVec (list [x, y, z])` – the origin of the line
>
> `toVec (list [x, y, z])` – the end of the line
>
> `color (list [r, g, b])` – the color of the line
>
> ```
> import bge
> bge.render.drawLine([0,0,0],[0,0,1],[255,40,0])
> #note: [255,40,0] is red in RGB
> ```

Comment: This is for 2D drawing in the game engine, not for creating a mesh. I believe that OP wanted to create a mesh.